# Publication Error: The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I got some requirement to implement transactional replication, so I am doing some research on it, but I am getting some issues while creating the publication. I have restored adventure works database for research purpose only. I created the distribution successfully but while creating publication I am getting the below error. I have administrator access on my windows credentials, and I have opened SSMS through Administrator permission. I did research on my part but didn't found anything.

```
SQL Server could not create publication 'AdvWorks2019_Pub'.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
------------------------------

The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.
Changed database context to 'AdventureWorks2019'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 50000)
```

I logged in SQL through windows authentication and while creating publication I have selected snapshot Agent and provide the windows credentials:
[image]

Here is my sql configuration screenshot:
[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) There is a "Copy Message" button in that image; use that and paste *only* the **relevant** part (the error).

Comment: Posting images of code/errors/data is almost always a *guaranteed* way of earning downvotes; I don't doubt that is the reason for the downvotes you received. Learn your lesson the hard way and going forward don't post such images. It could, however, also be due to that the question isn't on topic for [so], and is something that should be asked on [dba.se]; there are, at least, 2 migration votes on the quetion.

Comment: Adding images sometimes gives a clear picture, and easy to understand. That's why I put the screenshot. I have changed some tags as well. Thanks!

Comment: Images can do that, but images of errors do *never* do.

Comment: Have you seen https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/15b695e0-fdaf-46aa-adc3-f3c020028ae6/subscription-error-the-current-transaction-cannot-be-committed-and-cannot-support-operations-that?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: @Sergey : Yes I have seen this link. I have administrative rights on my account, but still its not working.